# Jenkins Configuration error

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting an error in Jenkins while running my build as mentioned in below:

[image: Jenkins error]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You should probably include a copy of the error message, (not an external link to a screenshot), and a description of what you already tried to solve that issue.

Comment: Have you checked the space? It looks like a space or a permission issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try to start a command prompt as an administrator